# how do I know if my wood floor is damaged?

Tags: wood, flooring, hardwood-floor, laminate-floor

I had left damp towels on the wood floors for entire day. Underneath it the floor was slippery and slightly wet. The wooden floor itself I don't know about other than its shinny and here's a pic of the area:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The floor will certainly dry out given time. If you want to speed it up, aim a fan at it. You could use a hair dryer, but don't get it too close and keep it moving.

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't swollen by now (it's been 6 months) then it's not damaged.

Comment: Yes it's not swollen, looks alright to me. Thanks.